# How do I stop gradle from applying the javafxplugin on java 8?

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I have a buildscript that is used on machines with java 11 and java 8, and as I use javafx, I would like to use the openjfk javafxplugin on java 11 to setup dependencies and disable the plugin on java 8 as it errors otherwise (because the plugin is complied on java 11).
I tried the following:

```
plugins {
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'application'
    if (JavaVersion.current() != JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8) {
        id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
    }
}
```

but this errors with

> only id(String) method calls allowed in plugins {} script block

So I'm not quite sure how to solve this...

Comment: Hmm. That works for me using Gradle 6.0.1 and the Kotlin DSL, though I see the same error when using the Groovy DSL.

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin/issues/61), it asks the same, but also gives a workaround. Also in the comments find a possible fix.